# How do I pass the data from the selected List to my controller as its always null

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Im pretty new to razor pages and selecting lists but I have this bit of code in my razor page in my .NETcore app 6.016

```
                <label for="Participants">Participants:</label>
                <select id="SelectedParticipants" name="Participants" asp-for="@Model.Meetings.Participants" multiple>
                    @foreach (var person in Model.People)
                    {
                        <option value="@person.Id">@person.Name</option>
                    }
                </select>
```

I want the @Model.Meetings.Participants to be populated by the selected items from model.People but its always null. All other items are being populated when the model is passed to my controller apart from the Participants

This is the Meeting class

```
public class Meeting
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime? MeetingDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }
        public List<Person>? Participants { get; set; }
        public string? Room { get; set; }

        public Meeting()
        {
            Participants = new List<Person>();
        }
```

I'm sure ive done something stupid but I can get this to work. Any advice would be appreciated.

I tried various combinations of using asp-for and asp-item I also tried to use javascript to add this but with no luck

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are passing `person.Id` instead of a `List<Person>` object. In fact, it seems that `select` cannot be directly bound to `List<model>`. The easiest way is to add a new property in `Meeting` to receive `person.Id`, and then use these `Ids` in the controller to obtain corresponding data to fill `Participants`.

I made a simple example, you can use it as a reference.

Models:

Add a parameter of type `int[]` to receive `person.Id`:

```
public class Meeting
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime? MeetingDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }
    //add this property
    public int[] ParticipantsIds { get; set; }
    public List<Person>? Participants { get; set; }
    public string? Room { get; set; }

    public Meeting()
    {
        Participants = new List<Person>();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{ 
    public Meeting Meetings { get; set; }
    public List<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();
    viewModel.People = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person(){ Id = 1, Name = "Name1" },
        new Person(){ Id = 2, Name = "Name2" },
        new Person(){ Id = 3, Name = "Name3" }
    };
    viewModel.Meetings = new Meeting();
    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ViewModel Index(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    List<Person> person = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person(){ Id = 1, Name = "Name1" },
        new Person(){ Id = 2, Name = "Name2" },
        new Person(){ Id = 3, Name = "Name3" }
    };
    //get Ids in viewModel and fill Participants
    foreach (var id in viewModel.Meetings.ParticipantsIds)
    {
        //If read data from the database you can use SQL Where()
        foreach (var participant in person) 
        {
            if (participant.Id == id)
            {
               viewModel.Meetings.Participants.Add(participant);
            }
        }
    }
    return viewModel;
}
```

View:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="index">
    <div>
        <label for="Id">Id:</label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.Meetings.Id"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Id">Title:</label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.Meetings.Title"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Id">MeetingDate:</label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.Meetings.MeetingDate" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Id">StartTime:</label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.Meetings.StartTime" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Id">EndTime:</label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.Meetings.EndTime" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Id">Room:</label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.Meetings.Room" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Participants">Participants:</label>
        <select id="SelectedParticipants" asp-for="@Model.Meetings.ParticipantsIds" multiple>
            @foreach (var person in Model.People)
            {
                <option value="@person.Id">@person.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

You can check whether the value submitted by the form conforms to your model in the developer tools of the browser:
[image]

Test Result:
[image]

[image]